# How can I synchronize database access between a write-thread and a read-thread?

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, mutex

My program has two threads:

1. Main execution thread that handles user input and queues up database writes
2. A utility thread that wakes up every second and flushes the writes to the database

Inside the main thread, I occasionally need to make reads on the database.  When this happens, performance is not important, but correctness is.  (In a perfect world, I would be reading from a cache, not making a round-trip to the database - but let's put that aside for the sake of discussion.)

How do I make sure that the main thread sees a correct / quiescent database?

A standard mutex won't work, since I run the risk of having the main thread grab the mutex before the data gets flushed to the database.  This would be a big race condition.

What I really want is some sort of mutex that lets the main thread of execution proceed only AFTER the mutex has been grabbed and released once.  Does such a thing exist?  What's the best way to solve this problem?

UPDATE: After doing some additional research, I might use [Boost's Conditional Variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) to address this problem.  Either that, or just bite the bullet and cache my writes.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have more than one main execution thread (ie, the only thread that will push writes onto the worker thread is the same thread that will be reading from the database), then you can probably just have a simple "pending writes" variable/function that you can check before sending a *read*, and spinlock or wait for a signal until the writes have been flushed.  It sounds like you won't need to perform any locking or synchonization on the writes, if they can simply be queued up to be processed by the worker thread.

Basically, as long as you are guaranteed that in between the check for that 'pending writes' state and when you actually perform the read, there are no writes, then you don't need to do anything too fancy.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed solution surely still results in a race condition, since a "write" may come in at any time, even halfway through a new event being queued.

A solution you might try is atomic database state value: you do your processing, then compare to an atomic state value to ensure that you are reading from a database that is in the state that is the same as when began the read.  If it's different, you start over.  This may be subject to starvation, but that's a separate issue.

Every time you change the database, you must compare and swap the atomic state value you used, indicating a change.

Answer (score 3):

Several solutions are possible:

- Have each thread open its own d/b connection and use it exclusively
- Use a single connection, but have each thread own the mutex to access it.

I don't see a problem with the second choice.  What's the harm of flushing when there's nothing to flush?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. If each thread has it's own db connection, they can still access the same table in the database. Nothing protects the first thread from accessing stale data that hasn't been yet been updated by the second thread.

Comment: Access contention of simultaneous writing, as well as reading and writing, is a standard feature of database managers. Since the question is tagged mysql, there should be no problem.

Comment: Let's say Thread 1 queues up an INSERT to a table Foo.  Then - before Thread 2 has woken up and flushed the write to the database - Thread 1 executes a SELECT statement on table Foo.  There is no access contention, but Thread 1 is still reading stale data.

Comment: So, why is stale data an issue at all?  There's always going to be a point at which some data exists, but has not yet been updated in the database.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that when the read takes place, it reads the correct data, not data that is 1 second old. I guess I'm looking for a way to ensure this without caching all of my writes in memory. (If I removed the 2nd thread entirely and just made all my database calls, reads and writes, directly from the main thread, stale data would not be an issue since the database would always be exactly up to date.)

Comment: So, the question is, where is this data coming from?

The problem is, you can't set any indication that the database is stale until you possess the data, and once you possess the data, the database is already stale.  The data has to come *from* somewhere, and that somewhere can't be synchronized with your program.

Comment: If you make all your database calls from the main thread, there is still potential that a write could come into that thread on a queue while a read is in progress, so you will still have the same problem.